# Velocity context Variable existing or beeing null

Tags: velocity

Is there a difference when putting a null value into the context of velocity or not putting the variable at all.

```
VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();
ctx.put("v", null);
```

or

```
VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();
-- no put
```

It looks like there is no because velocity does not check for existance.
Instead it grabs the variable from the map and gets in both cases a `null`.

Comment: Well, there could be some code that looks if the var exists in the keyset of the map and then reacts differently when the var is not existing or when it exists but has not value

Answer (score 0):

You can put the context into itself:

```
ctx.put("ctx", ctx);
```

and then in VTL:

```
#if($ctx.containsKey('v'))
  ...
#else
  ...
#end
```